# Reference service code within another App in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, microservices

Is it possible to create a singleton service within a “common-components” app and reference that within another angular application? The service’s function would be for CRUD operations that are shared between all the applications.

We have five angular 8 applications hosted in a microservice fashion.

Comment: Would you be able to create an NPM module and wrap it in a service for each of your applications? I've done this before with an CRUD SDK that was used on a frontend app along with several back end services.

Comment: This would rather depend on the project structure. Are using an angular workspace? Are all the apps in the same repo?

Comment: @Keeleon that is possible to create a module. Right now it’s built like a module (doesn’t run code but the component are created into a bundle). How would we reference that within the other applications?

Comment: @C_Ogoo it’s 5 different repos. All are hosted on different url endpoints and there’s a “main” app we will use for the apps to run on but They can all run by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [Nx workspace](https://nx.dev/web), it will fit perfectly your need.

You will be able to organize your code in different libraries, and then share them between multiple applications.

[Nx workspace](https://nx.dev/web) permits also to build fullstack applications with for example `React`, `Angular` and backend `NestJs` code in the same monorepo, and some common libraries (for interfaces for example).

Perfect for a `microservice` architecture.

Some recommended resources :

- [Sustainable Angular Architectures](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/aktuelles/sustainable-angular-architectures-1/) by Manfred Steyer
- [Using Nx at Enterprises](https://nx.dev/web/guides/monorepo-nx-enterprise) by Nrwl

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately for hosting the application we are singled to using cloudfoundry. As for the DDD approach, the 5 apps are separated to do specific domain tasks. To assist in this I would like to use that service application to do the data retrieval for the microservices.